# View Logs in Rake Task (Production)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, rake

I'm hoping for an answer to get logs to the terminal when I run this rake task in production (to staging app).

I created a rake task to update existing records in our DB. I tried first locally, and it worked quickly and got the output I wanted. Locally, I have 
**4295** tracks. Now I am trying to run this on my staging DB, which has **17,418** tracks.

I run `heroku run rake db:track_rank -a staging-appname` and get this:

```
Running `rake db:track_rank` attached to terminal... up, run.8608
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent in "production" environment.
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEWRELIC_AGENT_ENABLED=false environment variable or modify the "production" section of your newrelic.yml.
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Environment: production
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : No known dispatcher detected.
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Application: Marmoset Music
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : delayed_job not available: No DJ worker present
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Installing Sinatra instrumentation
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Installing Dalli Memcache instrumentation
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Installing deferred Rack instrumentation
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Installing Rack::Builder middleware instrumentation
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Installing Rails 3+ middleware instrumentation
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Installing ActiveRecord instrumentation
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Installing legacy Excon instrumentation
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Installing DelayedJob instrumentation [part 1/2]
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Installing Rails 3 Controller instrumentation
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Installing Rails 3.1/3.2 view instrumentation
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Installing Rails3 Error instrumentation
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:40 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
** [NewRelic][03/11/15 18:04:41 +0000 49202e1b-0783-4094-bf1a-969e03b61bab (3)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/375675/applications/2431422
Updating track's rank points in group #1
Dalli/SASL authenticating as 021dd5
Dalli/SASL: 021dd5
```

It's been sitting there for about 12 minutes, so I'm unsure if it's actually doing anything to "group 1".

How can I get some logs to the terminal to see what's happening?

Here's my rake task:

```
desc "Updates all exisiting tracks rank"


namespace :db do
    task :track_rank => :environment do 

      batch_index = 1
        puts "Updating track's rank points in group ##{batch_index}"

            three_weeks_ago = 21.days.ago.to_date

            Track.find_in_batches do |group|

                group.each do |track|


                    listens = track.listens_count
                    downloads = track.downloads_count
                    purchases = track.purchases_count
                    staff_pick = 0
                    new_track = 0


                    if track.staff_pick?
                        staff_pick += 1
                    end

                    if track.created_at.to_date > three_weeks_ago
                        new_track += 2000
                    end


                    downloads *= 60
                    purchases *= 150
                    staff_pick *= 1000

                    rank_total = listens + downloads + purchases + staff_pick + new_track

                    if rank_total > 0
                        track.increment!(:rank, by = rank_total)
                    end

              end       
              batch_index +=1       
          end       

        puts "Tracks updated!"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is to have Rails log the rake task progress and/or results explicetely. Just change this:

```
puts "Tracks updated!"
```

to this

```
Rails.logger.ingo "Tracks updated!"
```

You can also add some debugging logs in the middle, but it's up to you.

Comment: Rails.logger doesn't put anything in the Heroku logs from rake tasks, that I can see.  All you get are "starting ... stopped".  Everything in between, which you painstakingly told your task to output for troubleshooting, is missing.

Comment: @JosephK That's probably because the rake task doesn't find time to flush stuff out of the buffer. You need to flush them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Run `heroku logs`

You can filter the logs as well, take a look at the [types of logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#types-of-logs)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Heroku has an issue with logging rake tasks. To circumvent this, you need to run rake tasks in a detached mode.

```
heroku run:detached rake db:track_rank
```

Source: https://www.salsify.com/blog/engineering/capturing-logs-from-rake-tasks-and-rails-console-on-heroku